# I want to expand the lid, like making an eye more open. How do I go about it?

Tags: edit-mode

I want to expand the lid, like making an eye more open. How do I go about it? I tried selecting faces and moving them[image: This is the image], but it is not working.

Comment: What is your final goal? What kind of object are your trying to achieve? Will it be animated? Do you need so many faces? You could make your sphere stick to another one with a Shrinkwrap modifier so that when you open your lid it keeps a spherical shape

Comment: No it won't be animated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sphere (A) with less faces, rip (<kbd>V</kbd>) where you want to open the lid, create another sphere (B) that you subdivide to make it very spherical, hide it, make A stick to B with a *Shrinkwrap* modifier, activate the *Proportional Editing (Connected Only)* option and move the central face of your lid:

[image]

If you want a higher topology, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and apply:

[image]

Comment: Are you suggesting I create another model entirely following the steps you listed or is there a way to still do it on this existing model?

Comment: you can do the same with your current mesh, just duplicate your sphere in Object mode, rotate it 180° on Z and use it as Target of the Shrinkwrap

Comment: I'll try that out. Thank you